# Blender 3.1.2 - Solidify Modifier shrink issue

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I was working on a light saber model for a class I am taking and ran into a rather weird issue. The part I was working on was a cylinder which was nothing to crazy mesh wise. Went in object mode applied 'scale and rotation' selected the Solidify modifier, adjusted to the thickness I wanted and checked the 'even' box under the options of the modifier. Apply the modifier and then in object mode went to bring in another cylinder and the previous part with the modifier shrunk in size, considerably. So I performed a few undo's and tried to see if I didn't apply the modifier and it did the same exact thing with the modifier applied (shrunk).

[image: Before brining in the cylinder]

[image: After adding in the new cylinder]

Comment: Based on the colors of your transform box (N panel), I would guess you have keyframed your object's scale somewhere.

Comment: He also has the Auto Keying option enabled at the top of the Timeline window which is probably what caused the keyframe to be added!